# differenzial operation with two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

T and Z are two columns of double

how can I calculate c = k*(dT/dZ) ? it would be correct to use the diff function?

Comment: Sure, why not? `diff` computes differences, and differences are the standard way to approximate a derivative

Comment: such as c = k.* diff(T./Z); ?

Comment: I've just included an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the [definition of derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition) (without the limit).

- If `k` is a scalar:

  ```
  c = k * diff(T)./diff(Z)
  ```
- If `k` is a vector, use either of these:

  ```
  c = k(1:end-1) .* diff(T)./diff(Z)
  c = k(2:end) .* diff(T)./diff(Z)
  ```

  That's because `diff` reduces the number of elements by 1.